How to make this triangle using tikz? (specially the length is in parentheses of the dotted line)

The length is in parentheses of the dotted line

Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show the code ...

Please always show what you tried so far.
You can probably do something like this:
\documentclass[border=10Mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (-2,5);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);

\draw (A) node[above] {$A$} -- (C) node[right] {$C$};

\draw[densely dotted] (C) to[bend right] 
    node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] {$2\sqrt{5}$} (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks. Could you show me the angle alpha markings too?

@kosskoss: Please accept the answer - it is not allowed to move the goal like that. If you have a new question, you can make a new post - there is not limit. The angle marking can be found in many questions on this site.

@kosskoss You did not provide any code, so I could only guess what your issue is. Note that there are always multiple ways to solve things, which is why you should provide the code showing what you tried. This site is not meant to be a human-powered free image-to-TikZ conversion tool.

@hpekristiansen Even if it were allowed, it is really discouraging.

@Qrrbrbirlbel: I do not understand - It is always encouraged to not move the goal, accept answers and ask many good questions!

Thank you. You are right. I will follow the rules from now on.
And I accepted the answer.

@kosskoss Look at the pgfmanual.pdf for 'angles'; that is a ready to use syntax. ;)
